# How to clear a React Bootstrap textarea form control after the form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a form made with React Bootstrap to semply submit a string that will be saved on a DB. It works and the submitted message is saved, but I don't know how to clear the textarea when the message is submitted.

As you can see, what I tried to do is to use the useState hook to set an empty value but after the form is submitted the string is still visible in the textarea. Is there any way to do this?

```
const Form = (props) => {

    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);

    const handleSubmit = async event => {
        setLoading(true);
        event.preventDefault();

        const res = await fetch(
            // here I call the api
        )
        result = await res.json();
        setValue(null);
        setLoading(false);
    };


    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="text">
                <Form.Control as="textarea"
                              required
                              type="text"
                              placeholder=""
                              defaultValue={value}
                />
            </Form.Group>

            <Button
                variant="primary"
                type="submit"
                disabled={isLoading}
            >
                {isLoading ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}
            </Button>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Did you try using 'value' instead of 'defaultValue'?

Comment: Yes, same result

Comment: Checking in.. how did you go with this?

Comment: no luck, if I change defaultValue to value the textarea is cleared, however I can't type again anything and I need to reload the page.

Answer (score 2):

To my eye, your textarea is currently [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), and so any changes made to `value` won't be updated in the Form.Control component.

```js
   <Form.Control 
      as="textarea" 
      rows={3}
      value={value}
      onChange={e => {
         setValue(e.target.value);
      }
   />
```

Rather than using the `defaultValue` prop, I would probably use `setValue(props.value)` to reset `value` in your handler function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove value from props - Form component should hold this state. Then, for controlled input you need to change "defaultValue" to "value" on Form.Control. Also add onChange and set the value. On form submit you can set your value state to empty string, not null:

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-carson-wupp3i

Comment: I actually need props if I use the form for edit content.